# Hive Map Join. Hive picking the bigger table to store in cache

Tags: hive, inner-join

I have the below properties set.

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=true;
set hive.optimize.ppd=true;
```

Table A has 25 Million records. Table B has 44 million records. But there exists conditions on where clause which has filters on Table B. So, after applying the filters the number of records come down to 2 million.

Instead of processing the map join for table B, HIVE chooses table A. 25 million records are cached into all the data nodes.

Below is the query used

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4 
    from table_A a 
    join
   table_B c
    on
    a.account_number=c.account_number and c.ins_date between '$date_6' and '$date_cur'.
```

What should be done to make sure HIVE caches table B?

> Plan after including the Stream table hint on the larger table-
>
> **STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
>     Stage-4 is a root stage
>     Stage-3 depends on stages: Stage-4
>     Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-3
>   STAGE PLANS:
>     Stage: Stage-4
>       Map Reduce Local Work
>         Alias -> Map Local Tables:
>           b
>             Fetch Operator
>               limit: -1
>         Alias -> Map Local Operator Tree:
>           b
>             TableScan
>               alias: b
>               Statistics: Num rows: 23894045 Data size: 7048743275 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>               HashTable Sink Operator
>                 condition expressions:
>                   0 {cm_mac_fin} {wan_mac} {restart} {reboot} {day_id}
>                   1 {division} {region}
>                 keys:
>                   0 cm_mac_fin (type: string)
>                   1 mac (type: string)
>     Stage: Stage-3
>       Map Reduce
>         Map Operator Tree:
>             TableScan
>               alias: a
>               Statistics: Num rows: 2599797 Data size: 678547017 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>               Map Join Operator
>                 condition map:
>                      Left Outer Join0 to 1
>                 condition expressions:
>                   0 {cm_mac_fin} {wan_mac} {restart} {reboot} {day_id}
>                   1 {mac} {division} {region}
>                 keys:
>                   0 cm_mac_fin (type: string)
>                   1 mac (type: string)
>                 outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col8, _col9, _col10
>                 Statistics: Num rows: 26283450 Data size: 7753617770 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>                 Select Operator
>                   expressions: _col0 (type: string), _col1 (type: string), _col2 (type: int), _col3 (type: int), _col4 (type: date), _col8 (type: string), _col9 (type: string), _col10 (type: string)
>                   outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7
>                   Statistics: Num rows: 26283450 Data size: 7753617770 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>                   File Output Operator
>                     compressed: false
>                     Statistics: Num rows: 26283450 Data size: 7753617770 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>                     table:
>                         input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
>                         output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
>                         serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
>         Local Work:
>           Map Reduce Local Work
>         Execution mode: vectorized
>     Stage: Stage-0
>       Fetch Operator
>         limit: -1
>         Processor Tree:
>           ListSink**
>
> Plan after including the map join hint on the smaller table-
>
> **STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
>     Stage-4 is a root stage
>     Stage-3 depends on stages: Stage-4
>     Stage-0 depends on stages: Stage-3
>   STAGE PLANS:
>     Stage: Stage-4
>       Map Reduce Local Work
>         Alias -> Map Local Tables:
>           b
>             Fetch Operator
>               limit: -1
>         Alias -> Map Local Operator Tree:
>           b
>             TableScan
>               alias: b
>               Statistics: Num rows: 23894045 Data size: 7048743275 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>               HashTable Sink Operator
>                 condition expressions:
>                   0 {cm_mac_fin} {wan_mac} {restart} {reboot} {day_id}
>                   1 {division} {region}
>                 keys:
>                   0 cm_mac_fin (type: string)
>                   1 mac (type: string)
>     Stage: Stage-3
>       Map Reduce
>         Map Operator Tree:
>             TableScan
>               alias: a
>               Statistics: Num rows: 2599797 Data size: 678547017 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>               Map Join Operator
>                 condition map:
>                      Left Outer Join0 to 1
>                 condition expressions:
>                   0 {cm_mac_fin} {wan_mac} {restart} {reboot} {day_id}
>                   1 {mac} {division} {region}
>                 keys:
>                   0 cm_mac_fin (type: string)
>                   1 mac (type: string)
>                 outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col8, _col9, _col10
>                 Statistics: Num rows: 26283450 Data size: 7753617770 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>                 Select Operator
>                   expressions: _col0 (type: string), _col1 (type: string), _col2 (type: int), _col3 (type: int), _col4 (type: date), _col8 (type: string), _col9 (type: string), _col10 (type: string)
>                   outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3, _col4, _col5, _col6, _col7
>                   Statistics: Num rows: 26283450 Data size: 7753617770 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>                   File Output Operator
>                     compressed: false
>                     Statistics: Num rows: 26283450 Data size: 7753617770 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: NONE
>                     table:
>                         input format: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
>                         output format: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
>                         serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
>         Local Work:
>           Map Reduce Local Work
>         Execution mode: vectorized
>     Stage: Stage-0
>       Fetch Operator
>         limit: -1
>         Processor Tree:
>           ListSink**

Answer (score 0):

Hive internally uses multiple factors to determine cache table and stream table for joins:

It convert queries to map-joins based on the configuration flags(`hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask, hive.auto.convert.join.noconditionaltask.size, hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize`). 
The size configuration enables the user to control what size table can fit in memory.
 
Suppose n tables are partiipating in join then n-1 tables of the join have to fit in memory for the map-join optimization to take effect. 
When n=2 and the parameter `hive.auto.convert.join` is set to true then hive goes for mapjoins and cache the table which is smaller than `hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize` this parameter.

In your case, you may explicitly specify cache table instead of hive to determine it:

```
select /*+MAPJOIN(c)*/ col1,col2,col3,col4 
    from table_A a 
    join
   table_B c
    on
    a.account_number=c.account_number and c.ins_date between '$date_6' and '$date_cur'.
```

Comment: Hi Rahul- Will the hint work if we are performing a left join instead of inner join? I would need the outer table to be cached.

Comment: yes, in case of left join you need all records from one table so this table should be stream and another table of join can be cache or in-memory.

Comment: select /*+MAPJOIN(a)*/ col1,col2,col3,col4 
    from table_A a 
    left join
   table_B c
    on
    a.account_number=c.account_number and c.ins_date between '$date_6' and '$date_cur'.         Table A is small compared to table B and hence I would like Table A to be cached. I gave the hint, but still hive doesn't cache table A. it is caching table B. Any idea why?

Comment: try this: select /*+ STREAMTABLE(c) */ col1,col2,col3,col4 from table_A a left join ( select * from table_B  cins_date between 'pqr' and 'xyz') c on a.account_number=c.account_number.

Comment: Also share explain command response of both queries.explain select /*+MAPJOIN(a)*/ col1,col2,col3,col4 from table_A a left join table_B c on a.account_number=c.account_number and c.ins_date between '$date_6' and '$date_cur'

Comment: I have included the plans to the question section. I don't think it is in a readable format. But sorry, I am not sure how to format the text.

Answer (score 0):

Move your where clause to a CTE before join.

```
WITH b as (
  SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 
  FROM table_B
  WHERE ins_date between '$date_6' and '$date_cur'
)
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 
FROM table_A a join b
on a.account_number = b.account_number;
```

This way b which is the right side of the join has only 2 million records and therefore gets loaded in RAM.